# copy-list-initialization of std::map with std::variant as mapped_type

Tags: c++, c++17, initializer-list, variant, list-initialization

Why this piece of code compiles?

```
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <map>

void foo(std::map<int, std::variant<int, std::string>> map)
{}

int main()
{
    foo({{1,"1"}, {2, 2}});
}
```

We have `{{1,"1"}, {2, 2}}` thing which `std::map` should be initialized with. It probably has something to do with the `std::map` ctor which accepts `std::initializer_list` & list-initialization. But I wonder how this thing `{{1,"1"}, {2, 2}}` may compile at all? What type it has? How overload resolution works in this case?

Comment: It's a braced initialization list, that attempts to initialize the object, one onion layer at a time. It's quite annoying how, syntactically, it's similar to a 100%, original formula, prescription strength `std::initializer_list`, but it's own, separate beast. It would take a while to go through the standard and dig out all the gory details. Massive time sink.

Comment: The term you are looking for is *uniform initialization*.  If you google that, you'll find plenty of information.  It could almost use it's own book.  To make it even better, it isn't even uniform: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs

Answer (score 1):

First, in the example you give, there is no overload resolution. Well, not in the sense that there's any choice in overloads. Either the one function matches, or it doesn't; there's no picking order or templates or any of the complexities normally meant when speaking about "overload resolution".

The compiler tries to "map" `{{1,"1"}, {2, 2}}` onto a constructor of `std::map<int, std::variant<int, std::string>>`, which will work with `std::map`'s `std::initializer_list<std::pair<const int, std::variant<int, std::string>>` constructor (number 5 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map), summarily put: a list of the map's elements), but only if each element in that list can be constructed from the nested parts.

Here, two elements, `{1,"1"}` and `{2, 2}` need to be "mapped", separately, to a `std::pair<const int, std::variant<int, std::string>`, using `std::pair`'s aggregate initialization (meaning you can construct a `std::pair<T,U>` from a braced init statement `{t, u}` where `t` is a `T` and `u` is a `U`).
The second argument is more complex, being an `std::variant`.
Here, the compiler probably uses deduction guides (although I think this is an implementation detail) to construct the `variant` object from one of its possible alternative types.

A full overview of initialization can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization), although several pieces will need to be put together to come up to the above story. Note this is how I understand the process, could be that there are details that are different in the actual implementation or standard that I don't think would matter here, and might even impede understanding what is going on.

Comment: I had similar mental model of how it works. The tricky part here is "The compiler tries to "map" {{1,"1"}, {2, 2}} onto a constructor" and "two elements, {1,"1"} and {2, 2} need to be "mapped", separately". Moreover, android NDK doesn't build such a code, it throws an error `cannot convert initializer list argument to 'const cReportsManager::tNamedParams' (aka 'const map<basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >, variant<std::__ndk1::basic_string<char, std::__ndk1::char_traits<char>, std::__ndk1::allocator<char> >, long long> >')`

Comment: @DmitryKatkevich Starting from Clang/libc++ 5.0, this code can be compiled: https://godbolt.org/z/acxP6z. What version of the NDK are you using? The latest version has included `std::filesystem` so they must be using recent versions of the clang/libc++.

Comment: To be more clear I cannot fully undestand what _The compiler tries to "map" {{1,"1"}, {2, 2}} onto a constructor_ mean. There should be and object in the first place which then should be passed in the constructor. And I cannot understand how `{{1,"1"}, {2, 2}}` thing can be such an object.

Comment: @Dmitry A `braced-init-list` is a syntactical element that the compiler understands as an initialization expression, and in the context of a function call, it transforms this into a specific constructor call, creating the function parameter object. would you understand what happens if your function call looked like this? 
`foo(std::map<int, std::variant<int, std::string>>(std::pair<const int,std::variant<int, std::string>>(1,"1"), std::pair<const int, std::variant<int, std::string>>(2, 2));`
This is what the compiler expands the `braced-init-list`, `{{1,"1"}, {2, 2}}`, to.

Comment: NDK version 21.0.6113669

Comment: "Here, the compiler probably uses deduction guides (although I think this is an implementation detail) to construct the variant object from one of its possible alternative types." -- deduction guides change the type of the variant, which is not in play.  It is using overloaded constructors, which actually use overload resolution; but possibly via requires or sfinae it reduces the overload set to 1 or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Your code boils down to basically this:

```
std::map<int, std::variant<int, std::string>> map = {{1,"1"}, {2, 2}};
```

here we have a braced init list on the right of an object.  This indeed looks at the left and finds an appropriate constructor.

The one it finds is an initializer list.

So the above then boils down to this:

std::initializer_list<std::pair<const int, std::variant<int, std::string>>> il = {{1,"1"}, {2, 2}};
The braced-init syntax has no type, but can be used to initialize types, including initializer lists.

Here, it treats the inner `{}` as `std::pair<const int, std::variant<int, std::string>`, so this boils down to:

```
std::pair<const int, std::variant<int, std::string>> one = {1,"1"};
std::pair<const int, std::variant<int, std::string>> two = {2,2};
```

working.  This in turn boils down to

```
std::variant<int,std::string> v1 = "1";
std::variant<int,std::string> v2 = 2;
```

working, which *finally* boils down to the constructor of `std::variant` doing some SFINAE or requires magic to pick out the "right" constructor.